# Google maps drawing polygon autoselect points

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use google maps drawing tool in my angular 14 app.

```
public draw(): void {
   this.drawingManager.setOptions({
      drawingControl: true,
      drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
   });
}
```

All is working fine but I'd like to implement an "auto select points" when drawing. What I mean by auto select point is when drawing and when the cursor is near an existing point the cursor goes automatically to the point (so they'll share the same point).

Google already implements it for the LAST point of the polygon (try it https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools) which is great but I need the same behavior for points of existing polygons.

Is this feature possible?

Comment: Since snapping is at the end of the polygon point, how about filing a feature request? https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker